# Is it correct to define Angularjs, Nodejs and D3.js as "technologies"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, d3.js

I am writing my thesis and my doubt concerns the grouping AngularJS, NodeJS and D3.js, which I used to create my application, under the common name of technologies.
I know that they differ from each other but I want to put them all together in a chapter that I wanted to call precisely "Used Technologies"

Comment: This is off-topic for Stackoverflow, but yes, I think you can do that. I do

Comment: This might be better for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, they're definitely considered a standalone technology, all have rich ecosystems, strongly opinionated ways of handing data, solve specific problems and knowing any one of those "technologies" can land you a job...

Comment: From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/technology: _"1 : the use of science in industry, engineering, etc., to invent useful things or to solve problems 2 : a machine, piece of equipment, method, etc., that is created by technology."_ Almost everything related to a computer is a technology. According to this definition you should also list your mouse and keyboard in the list of used technologies.

Comment: Basically any single "software thing" can be called a technology. JavaScript is, as is Node.js, as is Angular, as is Rx.js, as is many others. It's not a particularly meaningful term, however.

Comment: Thank you all, you have clarified all my doubts.